# How I retrieve a 'standalone' symbol on Ruby's C extension API

Tags: c, ruby, symbols, ruby-c-extension

I want to return several values from a C function, and IMHO, a hash is a good option.
I first used `rb_intern('A_KEY')` to create the keys, but the extension crashed. Now, I am using `rb_str_new2`, but I prefer symbols.

How do I create a new symbol, and use it without referring to a class or a method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `ID2SYM` macro to convert the identifier that you get from `rb_intern` into a ruby symbol.  Try changing

```
rb_intern('A_KEY')
```

to

```
ID2SYM(rb_intern('A_KEY'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works without problem on 1.9